# How do you force a label to fill a WrapPanel line?

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

Lets say you have a WrapPanel with a labels:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Label Content="My Label" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Content="My Label 2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Basically, I want each of these to fill a full line in the wrappanel.  This seems like a simple thing to do, however, I can't seem to find out how.

I know that you can do it using the 'Width' property, however, I don't want a hard coded width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each label to be stacked, rather than wrapping, use a [StackPanel](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html) instead of a `WrapPanel`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="My Label" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Content="My Label 2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That would work for just those two labels, however, I have more Items that need to be wrapped.

Comment: You need to include those in your question if we are to stand a reasonably chance of answering. I would add the items you want to wrap to a separate `WrapPanel`.

Comment: @B-Rad What does "wrapped" mean when each Label fills a line? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes.  fills a line.  I think I want a WrapPanel to wrap vertically and horizontally at the same time, which just isn't the way things work.